# Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications toast notification only showing in debug mode

Tags: c#, windows

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=desktop#step-1-install-nuget-package).

I ran this code:

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
    .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
    .AddText("Andrew sent you a picture")
    .AddText("Check this out, The Enchantments in Washington!")
    .Show();
```

Nothing showed up, I ran it in debug mode I saw a notification, i'm new to c# and dotnet, and using vscode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue was it was closing quickly as soon as i added console.readline it worked.